# Springboot: Introduce delay between requests

Tags: spring-boot

I have a ask where I will get 200 parallel requests to spring rest service1 , service1 forward those to service2 but I need to delay 25seconds between the requests while sending to service2(service2 takes 30seconds process) .

tried following ways

1. If I use @RestController
   @RequestMapping , and added thread.sleep of 20 seconds, which is causing 504 because main thread blocking can't handle other requests
2. tried @asyn with thread.sleep of 20 seconds always throwing 500 to end user with org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException

what is the best way to handle this.

thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, **you need a queuing system**.

So let's start by creating a queue:

- we will mark it as `@Service`, so that we can autowire it from `RestController`. This class will be responsible for three tasks

  - enque
  - process queue (one item)
  - scheduled job runner
- now we can simply call this from rest-controller.

And we are done.

**Code:**

The queue

```java
@Service
public class OurQueueService {
    private final List<SomeDto> queue = new ArrayList<>();

    public void enqueue(SomeDto someDto) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(someDto);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5 * 1000)
    public void processQueue() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            if(queue.size()>0){
                  SomeDto thatDto = queue.get(0);
                  // now process it here, create a method if you want
                  queue.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use it:

```java
@RestController
public class RandomRestController {
    
    private final OurQueueService ourQueueService;

    @PostMapping("/enqueue")
    public String enqueueRequest(@RequestBody SomeDto someDto) {
        ourQueueService.enqueue(someDto);
        return "meaw";
    }
}
```

And to solve that lots of request at once, **you need load balancing**.

- Let's start by creating a `Dockerfile` for your Spring Boot application
- then create a `docker-compose.yaml` where we will add the load balancer
- run docker compose with as much instance as you want

**Code:**

Dockerfile

```
# ref: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/#A-Basic-Dockerfile
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  load-balancer:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    links:
      - webapp
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  webapp:
    build: .
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    expose:
      - "8080"
```

Run it with: `docker-compose up --scale webapp=<number-of-instance> -d`

Comment: thank you so much running scheduled job runner is't burden on the service? because requests receive limited time.I have @Service, and autowired it from RestController

Comment: @MagicTest, please check this. And if this resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted, and upvote it. And if you have some other thoughts or query, fire away. **Thanks.**

Comment: And as for your **scheduled job runner and burden on the service**, try an external queuing / messaging / event system, like kafka, rabbit-mq, or simply write yours. I'm not kidding, this is how great projects start. @MagicTest

Comment: thanks will try this, i don't have that freedom due to nature of env

Comment: thi is not working because all my requests are parallel if the main thread blocks with delay response 504 sent to service1 requester

Comment: @MagicTest added **load balancing** in the answer, please check